# Exception Not Handled in Guid.Parse Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've "inherited" a project that includes the following line of code:

```
        objLibPharmacy.UserId = Guid.Parse(Session["GroupId"].ToString());
```

When I run the debugger, I receive an error stating:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web 
request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it 
originated in the code.
```

The stack trace in part is as follows:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
```

UserControl_wuc_Pharmacy.bindPharmacyPopUp()

The bindPharmacyPopUp is as follows:

```
  private void bindPharmacyPopUp()
{
    /******************Bind Pharmacy Popup*********************/
    objLibPharmacy = new LibPharmacy();
    objLibPharmacy.PharmacyId = 0;
    objLibPharmacy.UserId = Guid.Parse(Session["GroupId"].ToString());
    objclsPharmacy = new clsPharmacy();
    objDs = objclsPharmacy.GetPharmacy(objLibPharmacy);
    string strFilter = "";
    if (objDs != null)
    {
        if (txtSearchPharmacy.Text != "")
            strFilter = "PharmacyName like '%" + txtSearchPharmacy.Text + "%'";
        DataView dv = objDs.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        if (strFilter != "")
            dv.RowFilter = strFilter;
        Utility.bindGridview(dv.ToTable(), gvPharmacyList);
        Utility.bindDDL(objDs.Tables[1], ddlPharmacyDetail, "Pharmacy");
        //ViewState["PharmacyTable"] = objDs.Tables[0];
    }

    /*********************************************************/
}
```

What is causing the null reference?  How do I handle such null reference in order for the debug to run without error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the name implies, the [Null Reference Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) occurs when you try to do an operation on an object that is not initialized, or have been dereferenced. In this case, you are calling `.ToString()` on `Session["GroupId"]`, which is probably not initialized yet.

The best thing to do would be initialize the GroupId session variable before accessing it. As a work around, you can skip the parsing if the variable is null :

```
if (Session["GroupId"] != null)
{
    objLibPharmacy.UserId = Guid.Parse(Session["GroupId"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This would happen if `Session["GroupId"]` is null.

You need to check for that before trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `Guid.TryParse` Method:

```
Guid userId;
if (Guid.TryParse(Session["GroupId"].ToString(), out userId))
   objLibPharmacy.UserId = userId;
```